# Keep call stack closed on breakpoint

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, callstack

Is there a way to keep the call stack panel collapsed in chrome dev tools? It expands every time i hit a breakpoint forcing me to scroll down to the scope. This makes debugging very slow and at times infuriating.

Thanks
/Eric

Comment: It's hardcoded in [devtools source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/sources/CallStackSidebarPane.js?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=120). You can complain on https://crbug.com and link the bug report here, also you can write a one-line patcher for resources.pak to disable the behavior.

Comment: This bug has been logged [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=656109) and [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=661293). Hopefully they'll get it fixed soon.

Comment: +100 for the questions. It is sooo annoying. How could only those Chrome devs make such a trash with open Call Stack tab.

Answer (score 4):

That was definitely a bug in Chrome. 
It has been fixed in [this commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/33b6a683ebb0ac3ea188bf5244f2cd6616babf9a) as of **3rd of December 2016**

> [DevTools] Don't expand CallStackSidebarPane on pause if it was collapsed
>
> BUG=656109

Should land in Canary soonish :-)

Comment: How about not Canary version?

Comment: If it's a part of a minor release (which I think it is) it should take up to 2 weeks from today, otherwise up to 5 weeks ([ref](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)).